# How do I integrate gpg with the GNOME keyring?

Tags: 11.10, gnupg, gnome-keyring, mutt

I use Mutt for gpg-signed email.  With previous versions of Ubuntu I could tell Mutt to use gnome-gpg, which would ask for my GPG passphrase with a GUI window and then store it my GNOME keyring for 24 hours or until logout, whichever came first.  However gnome-gpg was removed from universe in Ubuntu 11.10.  Is there a replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default keyring manager for GNOME is seahorse:

> Seahorse  is  a front end for GnuPG — the Gnu Privacy Guard program —
>   that integrates to the GNOME desktop. It is a tool for  secure 
>   communications  and  data storage.  Data encryption and digital
>   signature creation can easily be performed through a GUI and Key 
>   Management operations can easily be carried  out  through an intuitive
>   interface.

(`man 1 seahorse`)

It should be enabled/running by default in Ubuntu and you should have this variable in your environment:

```
$ echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO
/tmp/keyring-XXXXXX/gpg:0:1
```

`/tmp/keyring-XXXXXX/gpg` is a socket bound by the program `gnome-keyring-daemon`, which is found in the `gnome-keyring` package.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough information about your system and I cannot tell you how to proceed exactly. However I should have given you enough information to start investigating the problem. If you need more help, please tell me whether you have the package installed, whether the process is running, whether the socket exists and whether the environment variable is set.

Comment: Looks like all I needed to do was remove the custom `set pgp_sign_command="gnome-gpg ..."` setting from my `~/.mutt/muttrc`!

Comment: The embarrassing thing is that I did that ages ago, and seahorse-agent was working fine on my laptop.   I send most of my mail from my work account using mutt over ssh -- and ssh doesn't forward the GPG_AGENT connection, so I was typing in my passphrase multiple times a day anyway, without noticing I didn't have to do that for the rare personal email.  Whops.

Answer (score 1):

I think on 11.10, installing seahorse-plugins should do this for you. And I think in 12.04 and newer versions, the gpg integration will be built-in. I used to have to install seahorse-plugins to make this work in older Ubuntu versions, but on 12.04 I don't have such a package installed, and the GPG integration is working fine for me.

Comment: I'm on 11.10.  I don't have seahorse-plugins installed.  I have  GPG_AGENT_INFO in my environment.  I don't seem to have any seahorse processes running, though...  I think gnome-keyring-daemon is acting as a GPG agent for me.

Comment: Right. I'm not sure exactly what the plugins package does exactly, on a technical level. I never dug into the code to find out. I do know that not having it installed on older Ubuntu versions, would break the gpg+gnome-keyring integration on my systems. And I use gpg a lot with bzr and evolution.

Answer (score -1):

Gnome-GPG won't be avaiable for Ubuntu soon, but you can download the last builds that were made:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-gpg